# How to reduce the height of a SegmentedButton?

Tags: flutter

I'm using a SegmentedButton for the first time and was surprised it didn't center the text when I reduced its height to 25 using a SizedBox:

[image]

Here's my code. How can I reduce the height to 25 and keep my text centered vertically?

```
enum GoalButtons { todo, done }

class ToDoAndDoneRadioButtons extends StatefulWidget {
  const ToDoAndDoneRadioButtons({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<ToDoAndDoneRadioButtons> createState() => _GoalRadioButtonsState();
}

class _GoalRadioButtonsState extends State<ToDoAndDoneRadioButtons> {
  GoalButtons goalsView = GoalButtons.todo;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 25.0,
      width: 300,
      child: GetBuilder<SwitchController>(
        builder: (switchController) => MouseRegion(
          child: SegmentedButton<GoalButtons>(
            style: ButtonStyles.calendarToggles,
            showSelectedIcon: false,
            segments: const <ButtonSegment<GoalButtons>>[
              ButtonSegment<GoalButtons>(
                value: GoalButtons.todo,
                label: Text('TO-DO'),
              ),
              ButtonSegment<GoalButtons>(
                value: GoalButtons.done,
                label: Text('DONE'),
              ),
            ],
            selected: <GoalButtons>{goalsView},
            onSelectionChanged: (_) {},
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This got me interested, and I found that people have been having similar issues with this widget on GitHub recently.

I tried size-setting properties of `SegmentedButton` and they had no effects.

The only remedy for your specific issue I found works is:

```
ButtonSegment<GoalButtons>(
  value: GoalButtons.done,
  label: Padding(
     padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
     child: Text('TO-DO')),
)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Weird such an obvious bug made it into stable.

Answer (score 13):

A more appropriate way to do it would be using `style` by setting `visualDensity` between 4 and -4.
To further reduce the white space due to `tapTargetSize` use `MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap`

```
SegmentedButton<GoalButtons>(
  segments: const [
    ButtonSegment<GoalButtons>(
      value: GoalButtons.todo,
      label: Text('TO-DO'),
    ),
    ButtonSegment<GoalButtons>(
      value: GoalButtons.done,
      label: Text('DONE'),
    ),
  ],
  selected: <GoalButtons>{GoalButtons.todo},
  onSelectionChanged: (_) => null,
  style: const ButtonStyle(
    tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
    visualDensity: VisualDensity(horizontal: -3, vertical: -3),
  ),
);
```

[image: SegmentedButton VisualDensity]

Comment: Working for me.